# Trouble with PATCH operation using .NET Firely SDK for EPIC FHIR Integration

Tags: c#, .net, hl7-fhir

I'm integrating EPIC FHIR into our C# application using the .NET Firely SDK. I've successfully created a patient using the provided resources, but I'm encountering an issue with the PATCH operation. I'm strictly following the .net firely sdk documentation for doing the same. https://docs.fire.ly/projects/Firely-NET-SDK/en/latest/client/crud.html#patching-resources

I'm attempting to update a patient's birth date using the following payload:

```
var patch = new Parameters();
patch.Parameter.Add(new Parameters.ParameterComponent()
{
    Name = "OPERATION",
    Part = new List<Parameters.ParameterComponent>()
        {
            new Parameters.ParameterComponent()
            {
                    Name = "type",
                    Value = new FhirString("replace")
            },
            new Parameters.ParameterComponent()
            {
                    Name = "path",
                    Value = new FhirString("Patient.BirthDate")
            },
            new Parameters.ParameterComponent()
            {
                    Name = "value",
                    Value = new FhirString("2003-02-12")
            }
        }
});
var r = await _fhirClient.PatchAsync<Patient>(url, patch);
```

However, this PATCH operation is failing with an InternalServerError. The OperationOutcome returned contains the message "There was an error processing your request."

Error :
Hl7.Fhir.Rest.FhirOperationException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Operation was unsuccessful, and returned status InternalServerError. OperationOutcome: Overall result: FAILURE (1 errors and 0 warnings)
[ERROR] (no details)(further diagnostics: There was an error processing your request.)

I've verified the request payload, the URL, and the permissions. Could someone please advise on how to troubleshoot or resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Epic doesn't offer a Patient.Update FHIR API. If you're trying to update patient demographics via an API, you'll need to use a private API (available through the Vendor Services program only).

Comment: By Vendor services program, you mean the third party packages like firely .net sdk right? I'm using the same. They have provided PatchAsync extension method in their fhirClient. - @Ashavan

Comment: No, Vendor Services is the list of services provided by Epic (see https://vendorservices.epic.com/FAQ/Index?Question=1072&Category=1082). Their FHIR API is one of those services, but that service does not offer update or patch, so @Ashavan is suggesting you look at a different service offered by Epic if you need to perform them. Note however that it will not be a FHIR interface.